# Error configuring Azure Web App to use OneDrive for Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, onedrive

Saw the [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/september-update-web-apps-and-app-service-environments/) that OneDrive has been enabled as a source for continuous deployment in Azure Web Apps, and wanted to give it a try, for a demo video I'm putting together.

Unfortunately, for my primary Microsoft Account (the one I use as the login account for OneDrive on my dev machine), when I attempt to authorize the account for the Continuous Deployment feature in the preview portal, I get an error. Here's the error text:

> Failed to set up continuous deployment for web app onedriveDeploy, using OneDrive. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: OneDrive CreateFolder: Access Denied at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OneDriveProxy.d__6d`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OneDriveProxy.d__28.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OneDriveProxy.d__25.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.OneDriveSiteRepositoryProvider.d__1.MoveNext().

I've only managed to get the above error once. In every other case, I simply get a generic error message "Error retrieving data" with no link to further information. I've tested this on multiple Azure subscriptions, and multiple Web Apps. And once I get the error with this account, I cannot change the account for OneDrive continuous deployment, and the error then occurs consistently on any web app in that subscription.

I tried creating a new trial subscription, and created a web app and pointed to a different Microsoft Account for OneDrive authorization for continuous deployment, and for that account, the configuration succeeded. So I tried removing that and testing with the Microsoft account that had failed, and it failed on the new trial subscription as well, and again once it failed, I could not configure OneDrive continuous deployment to use a different account.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting would be welcome, as I'd like to include this feature in my demo video along with git and Dropbox.

Comment: I've asked the dev experts on this feature to take a look. It's still a very new feature, so there might still be some quirks.

Comment: Thanks, David. That was what I figured, given that it was only recently announced. Happy to provide any additional info needed to help repro.

Comment: Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please include the approx time of failed attempt (UTC if possible)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've since deleted the site, but I can see if I can repro on a new site, and will post that info.

Comment: Just tried again, with site name "testonedrivecontdeploy". Failed again, with the "Error retrieving data" error message.

Nothing shows up in the notifications, so no indication of any additional details available through the preview portal.

Comment: Looked at logs, seems like setup continuous deployment function is never get call, but failed when portal try to setup authentication with OneDrive.  Can you do two things: 1) go to https://resources.azure.com, expand providers-> sourcecontrols->OneDrive, to see if you have token there?   2) can you capture a fiddler or IE browser trace?  Thanks!

Comment: Another thing worth to try is to revoke access and start everything fresh. 1) go to https://account.live.com, after sign-in, Security & privacy --> Under Apps & Services click "Manage permissions", Click "Azure Web Apps" and click "Remove these permissions".  2)   The go back to https://portal.azure.com and try to setup continuous deployment with OneDrive again.

Comment: @XiaominWu: The problem account does have a token, as well as a refreshToken, and an expirationTime. The tokenSecret property is null.

Not sure if these properties are supposed to be editable, but I did try setting the token, etc. properties to null, but while resource explorer appears to save (PUT) the values, if I click away from the record, and select it again, the token values are still there.

I also did try removing the permissions, but the values are still there for that account.

Comment: we can ignore "tokenSecret", it is for OAuthV1, OneDrive is using OAuthV2.  In resources.azure.com, make sure you are at "Read/Write" mode (see at the top of the screen, there is a switch close to your profile picture and email)

Comment: @XiaominWu: Yes, I had already turned on Read/Write mode. Even with that turned on, editing the properties looks like it works and saves, but leaving the OneDrive node and then selecting it again shows that the save did not actually succeed.

Of course, now I looked again (trying in a different browser this time - IE11, vs Chrome last time), and the values appear to have been saved as null.

Comment: @XiaominWu: Even after clearing the properties that were there already, if I try to re-authorize that same account, it fails again with "Error retrieving data."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92795/discussion-between-xiaomin-wu-and-devhammer).

Comment: @devhammer, didn`t see any update from you. do you still seeing the issue?